# How to subset factor from dataframe at pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to use pandas.

I wanna subset factor from this dataframe.

I wanna subset state='Ohio' and year = '2001'.

```
from pandas import Series,DataFrame

data={
'state':['Ohio','Ohio','Ohio','Nevada','Nevada'],
'year':['2000','2001','2002','2001','2002'],
'pop':['1','2','3','1','2']
}
frame = DataFrame(data)
print(frame)
```

Thanks for reading.

I googled but I cant get clue to solve.

Comment: you mean `data[(data.state=='Ohio') & (data.year=='2001')]`?

Comment: I think `frame` is the name of the DataFrame here (not `data`) :-)

Comment: @ajcr ha! yes well spotted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter a dataframe you can use a mask:

```
In [171]:

frame[(frame.state=='Ohio') & (frame.year=='2001')]
Out[171]:
  pop state  year
1   2  Ohio  2001
```

For multiple conditions you must use the bitwise operator `&` in this case rather than `and` as you are comparing every element in the series, the braces (or brackets in The Queen's English) are due to operator precedence.

Alternatively you can use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas.DataFrame.query):

```
In [173]:

frame.query('state == "Ohio" and year =="2001"')
Out[173]:
  pop state  year
1   2  Ohio  2001
```